# Automatic string to date conversion

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc

I use spring 3.2.

On the web side, user need to enter two date

i try the server like this

```
http://localhost:8080/xxx/report/pendingBill?startDate=2004/01/02&endDate=2014/01/02
```

On the server side i have this code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pendingBill", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
@ResponseBody
public List<Bill> getPendingBill(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
...
}
```

I got this error

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'
```

I tried to write the date in different way, but i get alway the same problem.

Any tips?

Comment: How should Spring know the conversion to make? Check out `@DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date for value '2004/01/02'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '2004/01/02'"}

Comment: Well, what format did you use?

Comment: Have a look at spring @InitBinder or conversionService, and Converter interface

Comment: I've read up somewhre, you need to use long format of the date if you want the spring to take care of date conversion. So, try sending long date from the client date.getTime()